# Share RPi IP with mobile device to access Web Server

Tags: web-server, static-ip, access-point

I would like to connect a mobile device to the Raspberry Pi 4 Model B if possible without special software on the mobile device and start a script on the Pi from that device. My approach is to set up a hotspot on the mobile device to connect to the Pi, then use the Python REMote Interface library (Remi) as web-server via the Browser to start the script with a Button. To run the script properly I need an internet-connection.

**The Problem**: I need the IP-Address of the Pi to connect to the Remi web-server, which changes depending on the mobile device I use.
I tried to set a static IP for the Pi, but it doesn't work with different mobile devices.

- Is there any possibility to get the IP of the Pi without using a
  terminal?
  -> On Android it is displayed sometimes, but not on iOS.
- Or is there any way I can access the web-server without the IP?
- Or the other way around: Can I set up an access point on the Pi and
  still use the internet of the mobile device, after connecting it to
  the Pi?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there any way I can access the web-server without the IP?

Normally (as long as the device trying to access the web-server has [Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/) available), you can access it without knowing the IP address - you just need to know the `hostname` (e.g. `raspberrypi.local` would be the web address if the machine's hostname is `raspberrypi`). I haven't tested this from the device that is actually doing the hotspotting, it might only work for other devices on the hotspot (I was trying to find that out when I found this question)

For your other two points, I could think of particular situations where you could do those, but they don't work in general cases and/or work very efficiently.